# Multiple JQuery UI Dialogs open at once - positioning

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to open multiple JQuery UI Dialogs and have them arranged without overlap. Ideally I want to apply the equivalent functionality of **{float: left}** to each dialog, so that the first to open starts at the top left of a given container, the next to the right of the first, and so on.

I've already implemented a function to make each dialog, I just need to figure out the positioning issue (right now they open stacked upon each other).

Comment: perhaps you could store the position and size (height,width) in a variable and use that as the base position for the next diag that gets opened

Comment: My interim solution is to store a reference to the previously opened dialog and use the jquery UI position function to align the next dialog - essentially what you suggest. The logic becomes more difficult once dialogs start wrapping to the next "row", or the prior dialog is moved elsewhere or closed.